# Mesos + Marathon : json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string

Tags: json, docker, mesos, marathon

I am setting up a dockerized Mesos + Marathon cluster.
I have Mesos working fine with slaves, but I keep getting an error while trying to push the mesos-dns app through a JSON sent to Marathon.
I send :

```
{
    "container": {
        "docker": {
            "image": "192.168.0.38:5000/mesos-dns:generic",
            "privileged": true,
            "forcePullImage": true,
            "network": "BRIDGE"
        }
    },
    "id": "testdns2",
    "env": {
        "MASTERS": "192.168.0.38:5050",
        "RESOLVERS": "192.168.0.38",
        "ZOOKEEPER_MESOS": "zk://192.168.0.38:2181/mesos"
    }
}
```

to marathon, which create correctly an app, bu then I got the following erro on Mesos slave :

```
I1204 23:35:59.347939 14308 exec.cpp:134] Version: 0.25.0
I1204 23:35:59.350044 14313 exec.cpp:208] Executor registered on slave b9cef37c-d444-40c9-967b-01b9b3e98abf-S1
WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities, memory limited without swap.
ERROR: 2015/12/04 22:35:59 config.go:118: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string
```

Docker version 1.8.3, mesos 0.25, marathon 0.9

Any idea where the json could be faulty ?

Comment: Have you considered updating Marathon to a more recent version? 0.13.0 is out since a few days...

Comment: I am trying, but it needs java 8, and I didn't find yet a way to install it through a docker file (the oracle java installer seems not to accept a -y option :( )

Comment: Just use the official Marathon image...